# jQuery address won't bind on ajax-loaded content

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-address

I used this jQuery plugin:

> http://www.asual.com/jquery/address/

Eventually it has poor documentation. It doesn't want to bind on ajax-loaded content. For example, a link: a link from an ajax content which points to another page doesn't load via ajax but the window loads that page instead.

How do you bind the plugin for ajax-loaded elements?

---

[Live Demo](http://apathetic.undo.it/welcome/about)

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the plugin in a function, and use it in $.ajaxSuccess callback:

```
var bindAddress = function (elem) {
    var $elem = $(elem);
    if ($elem.data('isAddressed')) {
        return;
    }
    $elem.address();
};

$.ajaxSuccess(function () {
    $(yourElementSelector).each(bindAddress);
});
```

Remember, don't use `$(yourElementSelector).address()` method, use `$(yourElementSelector).each(bindAddress)` instead.

Comment: Hi, could you help me check how come it works on [this site](http://www.voidbrain.net/) ?